# Update single table from a Model with referential constraint without modifying referenced table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very specific question.
Below are the two models `appointments.cs` and `valid_clients.cs`. Both these models are mapped to the two database tables.

**appointmnets.cs**
.*It references* `valid_clients.cs`

```
public  partial class appointments
    {

        public int appt_client_id { get; set; }

        public int customer_id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int appt_id { get; set; }

        public DateTime appt_date_time { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("appt_client_id")]
        public virtual valid_clients Client { get; set; }

    }
```

**valid_clients.cs**

```
 public partial class valid_clients
    {

        [Key]
        public int client_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string client_name { get; set; }

        public bool valid_client { get; set; }
}
```

**Now, I need to update a single record in `appointments` table in database**. I have the following code in the controller method for update.But this code inserts a new record in `valid_clients`table as well and then inserts a new record in `appointments`.

```
[HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Confirm1(appointments appointment,string submit)
        {
            using (var db1 = new appointmentContext()){
                appointments app = db1.appointments.Single(d => d.appt_id == appointment.appt_id);
                app = appointment;
                app.appt_status = "RESCHED";
                app.time_stamp = DateTime.Now;

                //Saving the changes in the database
                try
                {
                    db.appointments.Add(app);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
                {

                }
            }
            return View("Edit", appointment);
        }
```

**Question:**
    **How can I keep my model structure same and just update a single record in `appointments` table without modifying `valid_clients` table.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code creates a new `appointments`.   It does not update an existing one.

If you want to update your model, you do something like this:

```
appointments app = db1.appointments.Single(d => d.appt_id == appointment.appt_id);
app.appt_status = "RESCHED";
app.time_stamp = DateTime.Now;
app.OtherValue = appointment.OtherValue;
db.SaveChanges();
```

and you leave out the lines:

```
app = appointment;
db.appointments.Add(app);
```

`app = appointment;` one does not actually edit the `appointments` that you had selected.  It just changes `app` to point to a different one.

`db.appointments.Add(app);` adds a new row, adn that doesn't seem to be what you need.

Comment: I made the changes as you mentioned but it doesn't update the existing record

Comment: @RudraniAngira what does your current code look like, and what are you looking for to make sure your record is updated?

Comment: I was using db instead of db1 the whole time. lol. Thank you for the help.